# How to fix Toolbar not changing titles until another tab is selected?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Im Facing a problem in my app. i want the app to display different titles on different tab toolbar and I quite made it. The problem is When i run the app I need to switch the tabs to make the setTitle work. I want by default when the app runs it should show the toolbar title as home.

Heres my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


private Toolbar mToolbar;

private TabLayout tabLayout = null;
private ViewPager viewPager = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Debanjan Vlogs");
    mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);



    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    //setting the tabs title
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_video_library));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_live_tv));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info));

    //setup the view pager
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new com.joy.skylake.utube.adapters.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {

                case 0:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    mToolbar.setTitle("Home");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    mToolbar.setTitle("Playlist");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    mToolbar.setTitle("Live");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    mToolbar.setTitle("About");
                    break;
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().clearColorFilter();
            tab.getIcon().clearColorFilter();

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });




}
```

Any Solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate more or give us an example?

Comment: @Ab ok. as you have seen, when you open the youtube app(older version) you see the toolbar shows home and as you swipe the tabs the text changes. I want to achieve the same thing but it seems like theres something wrong in my code so it doesnt shows Home when the app is opened. Instead it shows The app name. When i change the tabs then the titles get changed.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

```
mToolbar.setTitle("About");
```

try this

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("About");
```

Comment: Should have been a comment.

Comment: @Ab_ why? It's actually a right answer. If anybody in the future faces the same issue hi/she will find this answer and won't dig into the comments.

Comment: @Ab_ should I? Where can I find a SO rule with says that?

Comment: Rules don't explain everything. I'm not saying this has to be a comment. This should be a comment. The same way link-only questions are detested, answers with code only are also detested.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by using getSupportActionBar.setTitle("Home") in place of Debanjan Vlogs. As I had the issue that it doesn't change the title when it runs and displays the app name on the home tab action bar. So I got the idea to change the name Debanjan Vlogs to Home and everything became the way I expected